# Please rename tag [nullablereferencetypes] to [nullable-reference-types]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Please rename the [nullablereferencetypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nullablereferencetypes) tag to [nullable-reference-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nullable-reference-types). Most of the tags use the hyphenated form.